# How can I get more information about my video card on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card

After I typed "lspci", I got a message like this:

> VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

This gives me some information about my video card. But, how can I know more details? How much video RAM I've got? I know this is an integrated card, but I still want to know its specification.

Comment: 2nd Generation Core Processor would be Sandy Bridge. It's most likely either an Intel HD 2000 or 3000 depending on your CPU. As David said, check your CPU's specs.

Comment: hi, what about HardInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the specifications for your CPU, since it's part of your CPU. You have no video RAM, the video chipset has to use system RAM for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Find a command line, and type

```
head /proc/cpuinfo
```

There will be a few lines of output. One of the lines will start with "model name", likely the fifth line. This line tells you which cpu model you have.

Now, find your cpu on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors), and read about it there. A bit of clicking should take you a long way.